# How do you conditionally change a Set-Cookie header?

Tags: apache, cookies, header

The server behind my proxy sends back a `Set-Cookie` (response) header, which I want to change. I want to add `path=/` to this:

`Set-Cookie: DMZSID=none; HttpOnly; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`

So:

`Set-Cookie: DMZSID=none; HttpOnly; path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`

On occasion, this header also comes through the proxy:

`Set-Cookie: DMZSID=somethingImportant; HttpOnly; path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`

So in my inexperienced eye, there are two options:

### Always set path=/ when the cookie is called DMZSID

This seems to be the simplest option. I would probably try using `Header merge Set-Cookie path=/ env=someVariable` for it, but I don't know how to set up the `SetEnvIf` to trigger on the correct cookie name.

### Check if DMZSID=none and add path=/

I'd probably again use merge to add the `path=/` bit, but again, I don't know how to setup the `SetEnvIf` condition to trigger.

So how do I change this response header to always contain `path=/` when it contains `DMZSID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just found an easier way, after I found out you can use PCRE in `Header edit` in Apache. Simply put, this is it:

`Header edit Set-Cookie "(^DMZSID=none;\s?HttpOnly;\s?)(.*)" "$1path=/; $2"`

This edits the `Set-Cookie` header. First, it captures "DMZSID=none; HttpOnly; " exactly, with either 0 or 1 whitespaces between the attributes. After that, it captures the rest. Then simply replace by `contents of group 1` + `path=/;` + `contents of group 2`, and you get:

`Set-Cookie: DMZSID=none; HttpOnly; path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`

This could probably be done easier, by adding `path=/` to the very end, but I prefer to do it this way.